# What does `$page -= 1` in my PHP document mean?

Tags: php

I have the following variable defined in a PHP document I am working with, and I'm unsure what it means.

**The PHP**

```
$page -= 1;
```

The part I am unsure of is the `-=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-=` operator is shorthand for subtracting a value from the variable:

```
$x -= 1;
$x = $x - 1;
```

Here's some of the other ones:

1. `$x += 1;` (`$x = $x + 1`)
2. `$x -= 1;` (`$x = $x - 1`)
3. `$x *= 1;` (`$x = $x * 1`)
4. `$x /= 1;` (`$x = $x / 1`)

Comment: Very very helpful. Thanks so much! I commented on the answer above. Think you can shed some light on that?

Comment: `$page` is only defined once. If I do `x = 1` and `x = 2`, `x` is equal to `2` because that is the last value I told `x` to be. BTW, `x = 1` and `1 = x` are not the same thing, so `$cur_page = $page;` is setting `$cur_page`, not `$page`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Also, your answer was thorough and will be quite helpful in my future endeavours with PHP.

Comment: What would `"page="+page` mean?

Answer (score 7):

It's a shorthand to save typing.  It's effect is idential to

```
$page = $page - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-=` operator is a combination arithmetic and assignment operator. It subtracts 1 then reassigns it to `$page`.

Comment: So in my document, the following variables are defined: `$page = $_GET['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;` How can `$page` be defined as three different things?

Comment: It's defined once (the first time it occurs) and then operations are performed that modify it's value. So if `$_GET['page']` equals 10, then `$page` will equal `10` as well after `$page = $_GET['page'];`, then `$cur_page` will also be assigned a value of `10` and finally value of `$page` will be reduced to `9` after `$page -= 1;`

Comment: @Mchl One question. I'm guessing the reason the code isn't just `$page -= $_GET['page']` is for the `$cur_page` variable to be defined as the current page, correct? I suppose I could also use a different variable, i.e.. `$page_minus_one = $page - 1`, am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as `$page = $page - 1`, `$page--` or `--$page`, it's used to decrement the value of the variable.

Comment: Careful about `$page--` and `--$page`. They're almost, but not quite the same.

Comment: Yes, one get's decremented before the copy, when happens after, but the statements by themselves are effectively the same when used on a line all by themselves.